# Bound on the number of bounded primitive $k$-tuple for all unimodular lattices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, euclidean-geometry, integer-lattices, geometry-of-numbers

Let $X_d$ be the set of unimodular lattices in $\mathbb R^d$ (lattices with covolume one). For a lattice $\Lambda$ in $X_d$ and $1\le k \le d$, let $P^k(\Lambda)$ denote the set of all $k$-tuples $(v_1,\cdots,v_k) \in \mathbb R^{dk}$ such that $v_1,\cdots,v_k$ can be extended to a basis of $\Lambda$ (called primitive set or primitive tuple in some literature). Let $B(0,\delta)$ denote the ball centered at $O$ with radius $\delta$. I wonder what **upper bound estimate** can we give for the quantity

$$U(k,d,\delta):=\sup_{\Lambda \in X_d} |P^k(\Lambda) \cap B(0,\delta)^k|.$$

I found it is even hard to tell whether $U(k,d,\delta) <\infty$. I wish the bound could show how this quantity depends on $\delta$. I have a strong feeling that for $k<d$, the dependence of this quantity on $\delta$ is very subtle since it is always possible to shrink $k$ linearly independent vectors for a unimodular $\Lambda$ so that they become extremely small and thus fall into $B(0,\delta)$. If it is not dependent on $\delta$ then that constant for upperbound should only depend on $d$.

---

Update: this number seems to be infinite. Consider the lattice $Span \{\frac{1}{n}e_1,\frac{1}{n}e_2,n^2e_3\}$. Let $k=1$ and $n >> 1$. Then $\frac{m}{n}e_1+\frac{1}{n}e_2$ will provide infinitely many combinations in that intersection (they are all extendable to a basis of this lattice).

Comment: What happens to the volume of a unit cell when $v_1, ..., v_k$ are extended to a basis of $\Lambda$?

Comment: @JoshBone The volume of the "fundamental cell" should become $1$ for a unimodular lattice.

Comment: @KevinS Yes $B(0,\delta)^k\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{dk}$ not $\mathbb R^{k}$

Comment: @KevinS The key point here is that we can NOT FIXING the lattice. We are considering all unimodular lattices not just one

Comment: Can you provide some background textbook? I have an idea of how to prove but I need some more tools (i.e. proper definition of lattice and unimodular).

Answer (score 1):

*After some research...*
An **integral lattice**, $\Lambda\in X_n$ $\big($in $\mathbb{R}^n\big)$, is like a **(discrete) vector space**. You take a basis $\mathscr{B}:= \{\beta_1,...,\beta_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and then:

### $$\Lambda := Span_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathscr{B}) = \bigg\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\beta_i\text{ }\bigg|\text{ }\text{For }\lambda_i\in \mathbb{Z}\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\beta_i\in \mathscr{B}\bigg\}.$$

We say an integral lattice (spanned by $\mathscr{B}$) is **unimodular** if:

### $$det[\mathscr{B}] = det\big[\beta_1 ... \beta_n\big] = 1.$$

---

Now to bring in the **metric ball**:

### $$B(0,\delta) \equiv B_{\delta}(0):= \{p\in \mathbb{R}^n\text{ }|\text{ }d(0,p)<\delta\}$$

---

*In this problem, we are mainly concerned with counting the $\color{red}{\text{number of grid points inside a metric ball}}$. Then, comparing this number across all lattices in the space $X_n$.*

---

Using a given **norm**, $||\cdot||$, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we may quantify this number as:

### $$\color{red}{N(\Lambda,\delta)}:= \sum\limits_{i=1}^nN_i,$$

where

### $$\color{red}{N_i}:= floor\bigg(\frac{\delta}{||\beta_i||}\bigg).$$

*Elaborating, we take the radius, $\delta$, from the metric ball around the origin, and see how many lengths of a basis vector, $||\beta_i||$, fit inside this radius (i.e. divide). Then the floor just makes it the nearest integer (in $\mathbb{N}$).*
*Assumption: This sum doesn't account for all linear combinations, but gives a skeleton of points to compare for each basis. If $\Lambda_1$ has more skeleton points than $\Lambda_2$ inside the ball, it will also have more linear combinations of points inside the ball. [Pf: Exercise]*

---

Define the $\color{red}{\text{standard lattice}}$:

### $$\color{red}{\Lambda_0} := Span_{\mathbb{Z}}\big(\{\partial_1,...,\partial_n\}\big)$$

as the integer span of standard unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (trivially $det\big[\partial_1 ...\partial_n\big] = 1$, making $\Lambda_0$ unimodular).

---

Lastly, take arbitrary unimodular $\Lambda\in X_n$. Then:

### $$\exists T: \text{ }\mathscr{B} = T\mathscr{B}_0,$$

where $T\in SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is an invertible, unit determinant, real matrix. [Pf: Exercise]

---

So, we may compare basis vectors with the standard basis vectors:

### $$\forall i, \exists j:\text{ }\beta_i = T(\beta_{0,j}).$$

This implies:

### $$N(\Lambda,\delta) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n floor\bigg(\frac{\delta}{||\beta_i||}\bigg) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n floor\bigg(\frac{\delta}{||T(\beta_{0,j})||}\bigg).$$

Considering this term-wise, we have by *Submultiplicativity* of the norm:

### $$\frac{\delta}{||T(\beta_{0,j})||}\leq ||T||\cdot\frac{\delta}{||\beta_{0,j}||}$$

This gives us:

### $$\color{blue}{N(\Lambda,\delta) \leq ||T||\cdot N(\Lambda_0,\delta)}.$$

---

---

Depending on the two bases involved, $T$ will vary. There are two cases:

### $$\color{red}{||T||\leq 1} \implies ||T||\cdot N_0 \leq N_0$$

by the *Positive Scaling* property the inequality relation. Then by Transitivity it follows:

### $$N\leq N_0.$$

*So we have a set of lattices that are comparable with the **standard lattice** (they all have less points in the ball). It makes sense here to say:*

### $$\forall \Lambda:(||T||\leq 1)\implies \text{ }\text{ }|P^k(\Lambda)\cap B(0,\delta)^k|\leq \bigg(\begin{matrix}\widetilde{N_0}\\k\end{matrix}\bigg).$$

*where $\widetilde{N_0}\geq N_0$ adds the meat to the skeleton.*
*In the other case, we have no conclusive inequality because they conflict. So we are unable to compute the **supremum** for $U(k,n,\delta)$, but we get close!*

### $$\sup\limits_{\Lambda\in X_n^{\leq 1}}|P^k(\Lambda)\cap B(0,\delta)^k|\leq \bigg(\begin{matrix}\widetilde{N_0}\\k\end{matrix}\bigg)$$

*using the definition of **least upper bound**.*